# unit testing dependencies not being mocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I'm trying to add jest unit testing to my new react-redux project. I've created my first test file to test one of my containers, something like:

```
jest.unmock('../../src/containers/event-form')

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import EventForm from '../../src/containers/event-form'

describe('EventForm', () => {
})
```

in the event-form.js file I'm importing a function from actions, ie:

```
import { postEvent } from '../actions/index'
```

and in the actions.index.js file I'm importing axios module:

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

If I try to run the test at this point I'm getting errors from the axios code:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'defaults' of undefined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/export/www/soccer.hub.testui/node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js:83:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/export/www/soccer.hub.testui/node_modules/axios/index.js:1:137)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/export/www/soccer.hub.testui/src/actions/index.js:7:62)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/export/www/soccer.hub.testui/src/containers/event-form.js:4:40)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/export/www/soccer.hub.testui/__tests__/containers/event-form-test.js:6:44)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
```

I thought that the whole thing with jest was that everything was mocked. How is it that the actions/index.js seems to be getting initialised along with it's imports?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm having similar problems with Jest and axios.

Answer (score 0):

You need mock `axios` module using `jest.mock()`. This is an old question if you still need help. I am glad to help.